# React state me devuelve undefined al iterar en una lista

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Problema**: Tengo una lista en el `state` con links, cuando hago un `console.log(this.state.Fotos)` funciona y loguea los links, pero cuando accedo a ellos por `index` obtengo `undefined`, por alguna razón la cual desconozco.

## State

```
  state = {
    loading: true,
    Equipo: "",
    Jugadores: [],
    FotosGeneral: [],
    Fotos: []
  };
```

## Código del error

```
    const jugadoresJSX = [];
          this.state.Jugadores.forEach((jugador, index) => {
            if (
              jugador.actualizacion === "25-04-2021" &&
              jugador.equipos === this.state.Equipo
            ) {
              jugadoresJSX.push(
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="card-container" key={jugador.id}>
                    <div className="image-container">
                      {console.log(this.state.Fotos),
                      console.log(index)}
{//Aquí es donde se encuentra el problema
}
                      <img src={this.state.Foto[index]} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-content">
                      <div className="card-title">
                        <h3>{jugador.jugador}</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            }
          });
```

Comment: Bueno, en `console.log` tienes `this.state.Fotos`, y en el `img src` tienes `this.state.Foto[index]`, no será `this.state.Fotos[index]`? saludos

Comment: También en el `forEach`, la iteración es sobre `this.state.Jugadores`, ¿No será `this.state.Fotos.forEach`?